# Get a nested section of a For loop to move together with the outer

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I've a loop which goes through a worksheet and edits cell colour dependent on what is in another cell.

All this code is executed from MS Access on an Excel worksheet which the database exports.

```
For StartingCoumn2 = 11 To 14
    Column2 = StartingCoumn2
    For startingColumn = 15 To 18 'What columns we looking for
        ColumnCalc = startingColumn
        For startingRow = StartRow To LastWeekEndRow
            If .Cells(startingRow, ColumnCalc).Value = 0 Then
                .Cells(startingRow, ColumnCalc).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            ElseIf .Cells(startingRow, ColumnCalc).Value >= .Cells(startingRow, Column2).Value Then
                .Cells(startingRow, ColumnCalc).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
            ElseIf .Cells(startingRow, ColumnCalc).Value < .Cells(startingRow, Column2).Value Then
                .Cells(startingRow, ColumnCalc).Interior.ColorIndex = 44
            Else
                .Cells(startingRow, ColumnCalc).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            End If
        Next startingRow
    Next startingColumn
Next StartingCoumn2
```

My problem is `startingColumn` and `StartingCoumn2` need to move both +1 when it finishes the rows.

For example, I have filled in the code hopefully this helps people conceptually

```
For StartingCoumn2 = 11 To 14
    Column2 = 11
    For startingColumn = 15 To 18 'What columns we looking for
        ColumnCalc = 15
        For startingRow = 9 To 12
            If .Cells(9, 15).Value = 0 Then
                .Cells(9, 15).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            ElseIf .Cells(9, 15).Value >= .Cells(9, 11).Value Then
                .Cells(9, 15).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
            ElseIf .Cells(9, 15).Value < .Cells(9, 11).Value Then
                .Cells(9, 15).Interior.ColorIndex = 44
            Else
                .Cells(startingRow, ColumnCalc).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            End If
        Next startingRow
    Next startingColumn
Next StartingCoumn2
```

When it finishes the row and moves to the next column that needs editing (`startingColumn`) the comparing Column(`StartingCoumn2`) doesn't move, meaning the wrong columns are being compared.

```
For StartingCoumn2 = 11 To 14
    Column2 = 11
    For startingColumn = 15 To 18 'What columns we looking for
        ColumnCalc = 16
        For startingRow = 9 To 12
            If .Cells(9, 16).Value = 0 Then
                .Cells(9, 16).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            ElseIf .Cells(9, 16).Value >= .Cells(9, 11).Value Then
                .Cells(9, 16).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
            ElseIf .Cells(9, 16).Value < .Cells(9, 11).Value Then
                .Cells(9, 16).Interior.ColorIndex = 44
            Else
                .Cells(startingRow, ColumnCalc).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            End If
        Next startingRow
    Next startingColumn
Next StartingCoumn2
```

How do I get `StartingCoumn2` to move at the same time? I have tried Next `startingColumn`, `StartingCoumn2` but nothing happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need isn't another for loop.  You just need an offset value.  You're trying to compare two columns in the same row that are a static value apart.  So don't loop, but just add the offset.

For example, you have: `.Cells(startingRow, ColumnCalc).Value >= .Cells(startingRow, Column2)`

You'd change all instances of `Column2` to `ColumnCalc + 4`.

Then whenever it moves to the next column, it'll automatically check the offset column.